# Wordpress Form Submission Data Storage for Non-native Wordpress Fields

Tags: php, wordpress

Where does form submission data go from wordpress wp_insert_user go if there is not already usermeta field names that match?

Specifically, I included Company Name and Phone as fields in the form submission, however when I pull the data from the wp_users and wp_usermeta table I do not see these new fields.

Code that handles the wp_insert_user function:

```
if(empty($errors)){
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
'user_login'       =\> $user_login,
'user_pass'        =\> $user_pass,
'user_email'       =\> $user_email,
'first_name'       =\> $user_first,
'last_name'        =\> $user_last,
'company'          =\> $user_company,
'user_registered'  =\> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'role'             =\> 'subscriber',
));
```

I tried the above code and expected to see these fields in either the user or usermeta tables, though I did not.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/#parameters clearly lists all the properties you _can_ set using this. Nowhere does it say that you can just willy-nilly add your own arbitrary stuff. Here is what you should be using for custom user meta data: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/#programmatically

Comment: Yea, figured it out and used update_user_meta() to add the company and phone after the initial wp_insert_user() call.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you added two new fields "Company Name" and "Phone" to registration form and you are trying to save their values as user metadata, then you need to pass those values as key-value pairs in the $userdata array as per the below code:

```
$userData = array(
    'user_login' => $user_login,
    'user_pass' => $user_pass,
    'user_email' => $user_email,
    'first_name' => $user_first,
    'last_name' => $user_last,
    'company' => $company,
    'phone' =>   $phone,
    'user_registered'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'role'             => 'subscriber'
);

$userId = wp_insert_user( $userData );
```

After the user creation, you can fetch these fields from the wp_usermeta table using the get_user_meta function in WP. Try below code:

```
$company = get_user_meta( $userId, 'company', true );
$phone = get_user_meta( $userId, 'phone', true );
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I needed to add a update_user_meta() call after the wp_insert_user() call with the company and phone information. CBroe comment above also gives the link to documentation for this above.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this documenation for additional details. You are not able to add items outside the specifics of the wp_insert_user() options, though you *can* specify additional user meta data by using the update_user_meta() function as displayed below.

I needed to make the initial wp_insert_user(array) call, then using the same $user_id from that call, I could insert the user meta by calling update_user_meta().

documentation link: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/#programmatically

Code:

```
if(empty($errors)){
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
'user_login'       =\> $user_login,
'user_pass'        =\> $user_pass,
'user_email'       =\> $user_email,
'first_name'       =\> $user_first,
'last_name'        =\> $user_last,
'user_registered'  =\> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'role'             =\> 'subscriber',
));

if($new_user_id){
            update_user_meta( $new_user_id, "user_company", $user_company);
            update_user_meta($new_user_id, "user_phone", $user_phone);
        }
```